# Reading if-statement one by one

Tags: android

Bassicly i want the user to input "4" and then display the next question but when the user }
                q=1;

Comment: I think we need more of your code to understand how your program flows. Also, formatting your curly braces would make it a lot easier to read.

Comment: How about replacing the second if with "else if"?

Comment: i tried replacing it to else if but it gives me an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An else if might work (depending on if this is in a loop or what) but the most important thing here to learn is how the && operator works. When you have two statements separated by && the one appearing first will execute first.. If the result is false the second statement will not execute at all. However you don't want to ask the question at all in the second if statement if q == 0

Since you are comparing what the user entered within the if statement, what is happening is that even though the question == 0 the second part of the if is not executing until after you asked the question.
You should be the q == ? condition first in both cases (or if there are only 2 questions use else as shown by brawk1990)

I would at least change your code to this:

```
if (q == 0 && "4".equals(answer.getText().toString()))
{
    display1.setText("Correct");
    display.setText("4 + 9 =");
    answer.setText("");
    score++;
    q=1;
} 
if (q == 1 && "13".equals(answer.getText().toString())){
    display1.setText("Incorrect");
}
```

There are a lot of better ways to do this though but this looks like some kind of homework so I'm guessing you have to do it a certain way. As someone else suggested I think a case statement would be better, but we really need to see more of the program/assignment to give good advice there.

Comment: i appreciate the lengthy reply, really gave me an insight that was needed. And im creating a basic maths quiz for my uni project

Answer (score 1):

Won't a simple "else if" do what you want?

Comment: but he wants to go to the second question if the first was right.. Really this should be in a loop

Answer (score 0):

According to the part of the code you have sent, the syntax is bad too.

Write this instead:

```
if ("4".equals(answer.getText().toString())&& q==0)
{
    display1.setText("Correct");
    display.setText("4 + 9 =");
    answer.setText("");
    score++;
    q=1;
}else {
    display1.setText("Incorrect");
}
```

By the way, you could use a switch on variable q, so the code will be easier to read :)